# Is there a tablet-like desktop or theme that works well with touch screens?

Tags: debian, desktop, lxde, openbox, theme

I am trying to find either a desktop or desktop theme that works well with a touch screen.

What I need must be as light weight as possible, compatible with debian stretch (preferably) or other *buntu derivatives, and work well with fingers on a smallish (15") touchscreen.

The application is not quite a kiosk and there is some necessary interaction with the desktop, but 80-90% of the interaction will be done with a touchscreen.  a keyboard and mouse is available, but not readily accessible and rather a pain to get to.

what i have right now is debian stretch with lxde and i would prefer to keep debian if possible because it is running a rt-preempt kernel and i dont want to have to reinstall, recompile etc.

Does anyone know of a tablet like de or theme that would fit these requirements?  currently all of the window buttons are just too small and even scaled up you have about a 50-50 chance of closing or maximizing the window!

Comment: Welcome to the the Unix and Linux stack exchange! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to the site. Take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) if you are not familiar with how this site works. This question is potentially off-topic for this site. These types of questions prompt opinion-based answers as what is lightweight or touch screen compatible is largely up to interpretation as a solution for one person may not be suitable for your use case.

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear, but i am not looking for opinions but options.  what i really need to know is does this creature exist?  and does it come in the form of a desktop, a theme or something inbetween.  i can figure out myself if it works, but unless i am asking the wrong questions, google seems to have let me down this time